# How to pass single element from list to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of objects in my viewModel, like this:

```cs
    public class BusinessServicesViewModel
    {
        public List<ServiceViewModel> Services { get; set; }
        public ServiceViewModel NewService { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to edit single element from this list in view:

```cs
@for (i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="editServiceModal_@i" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editServiceModal_@i" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editServiceLabel_@i">Edytuj usługę @Model.Services[i].Name</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("EditService", "BusinessSite"))
                {
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Services[i].Name)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Services[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Services[i].Duration)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Services[i].Duration, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "1", max = "1440" })
                        </div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Services[i].Id)
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Zapisz" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In controller i made it like this:

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Business")]
        public ActionResult EditService(BusinessServicesViewModel model)
        {
            var userId = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            BusinessServicesViewModel modelToReturn;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                modelToReturn = GetBusinessServicesViewModel(userId);
                modelToReturn.NewService = model.NewService;
                return View("Services", modelToReturn);
            }
            var user = _contex.Users.Include(u => u.Business.Services).Single(u => u.Id == userId);
            var service = user.Business.Services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == model.Services[0].Id);

            service.Duration = model.Services[0].Duration;
            service.Name = model.Services[0].Name;

            if (_contex.SaveChanges() > 0)
            [...]
}
```

For first element from list, this works. Controller gets list with single item. I thought, that view always pass list with only one item that is in form. That's why i wrote somethink like this: `service.Duration = model.Services[0].Duration;`

But for other items, controller gets null list. It looks like it want pass item with index for example 3, but previous indexes do not exists, so it is null in overall.

I don't want to pass list with all items, because it is quite large, i only want to pass one element.
Also i would like to use this list and `@Html.TextBoxFor` because it nicely populate textBox with current values.

So, is there any solution to pass list with one item? Or how can I do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit just one item, you should only pass 1 item (if possible)

A start would be to change you're functions signature to handle a single service model:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Business")]
public ActionResult EditService(ServiceViewModel model)
```

Now, for this to work, you'll need to make sure you pass the correct data to your form. It's seems that your form-data and your model are a match and it will work. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, i also had to change helper methods: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Services[i].Name);` to raw html `<input class="form-control" [...] name="Name" [...] value="@Model.Services[i].Name"/>`